# Target text with jQuery in swf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF file which is connected to XML, i don't know how to target links inside the SWF without getting new the .fla or .swf file. i want to do it with jQuery or Javascript any help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access from `javascript` to content inside of `.swf` file. This type of elements works in a browsers with a plugin, this file are a it's binary code compile exclusives for the plugin.